# Cisco SR520W-ADSL-K9 + Mac/iPad/iPhone = "The negotiation with the VPN server failed. Verify the server address and try reconnecting."

Tags: vpn, cisco, mac, iphone, ipad

I am seeing the following error when attempting to connect to an Cisco 520 Secure Router /w 802.11g SR520W-ADSL-K9 with Mac, iPad or iPhone clients

"The negotiation with the VPN server failed. Verify the server address and try reconnecting."

I've double-checked all our settings and looked at various issues people are facing online but been able to find a solution as yet. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you logged in successfully with another VPN Client?

Comment: Yes, no problems with a the Cisco VPN client from a Windows machine.